# Like Operator of Mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$inputchar = $_GET["inputChar"];
$r = $inputchar;
$result = mysql_query("Select * from foodlist WHERE foodname LIKE '$r'") 
            or die(mysql_error());
```

In this I am collecting the value in $r from user and suppose user is enter roti there then i want to pick all the foodlist which contains roti words.

Comment: Use `LIKE '$r%'` that will find everything starting with `roti`. However, if your row(s) does contain only `roti` then you don't need to use `LIKE` just do `WHERE foodname = '$r'`

Comment: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM \`foodlist\` WHERE \`foodname\` LIKE '$r%'")` Also consider using an OO approach.

Comment: Not start or end with roti  i want like that  Suppose  I have food name like this " tabe ke roti" ,"Plain roti normal", "palin roti with butter".......... and suppose user is typing roti only then also these food item should appear there.

Comment: Try `WHERE foodname LIKE '%$r%' OR LIKE '%$r' OR LIKE '$r%'` that will find everything.

Comment: Also try `WHERE foodname LIKE '% $r %' OR LIKE '% $r' OR LIKE '$r% '` with spaces like that. Spaces do matter.

Comment: So... 2 of my comments above; any work for you?

Comment: No Still not achieving  the same

Comment: Funny; you accepted an answer with what I wrote originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the simple logic in PHP and then execute query conditionally.

```
$inputchar = $_GET["inputChar"];
if($inputchar == 'roti') {
    $result = mysql_query("Select * from `foodlist`") 
            or die(mysql_error());
} else{
    $r = $inputchar;
    $result = mysql_query("Select * from `foodlist` WHERE foodname LIKE '%$r%' OR LIKE '%$r' OR LIKE '$r%'") 
            or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: [Nice edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293037/like-operator-of-mysql-with-php#comment46782666_29293037). Why not just [use this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293037/like-operator-of-mysql-with-php#comment46782702_29293037) while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LIKE '%$r%'`, hovewer remember that since you accept user input you should really escape the value using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or, even better, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search within a text field for all values containing a certain string, you want to add wildcards (`%`).

This should work for you:

```
$inputchar = mysql_real_escape($_GET["inputChar"]);
$r = $inputchar;
$result = mysql_query("Select * from foodlist WHERE foodname LIKE '%$r%'") 
            or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: How , please give me a example.

Comment: @NaveenKumarMishra: please go through [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).